# How to analyse the sensitivity in argmax in exponential mechanism of differential privacy?

Tags: differential-privacy

Consider we have a database $D=[1,2,1,3]$, and the query for $\mathop{\arg\max}_{i} D_i$. So how to analyse the sentivity of the utility function?

for the sensitivity of $u$ equals to $\Delta u=\max_{i} \max_{D,D':\Vert D-D'\Vert_1\leq 1}\|\mathop{\arg\max}_{i} D_i-\mathop{\arg\max}_{i} D'_i\|$

Is it necessary to set an upper bound of $D_i$ to have the sensitivity of the utility function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The sensitivity is going to be very high. You cannot privately identify which person has the highest value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So is it possible to normalize the data and have all $D_i \in [0,1]$? Thereby we have the sensitivity $\Delta u = 1$.